# android facebook sdk errors

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I imported the sample projects from the facebook sdk into my eclipse environment. When building the projects I keep on getting the following error:

`Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.`

I have tried to do Android Tool > Fix Project Properties and also I have gone to Properties > Java Compiler and set the Compiler Compliance Level to 1.6 but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem with my workspace. My workspace was set to 1.7 so even if I set the specific Compiler Compliance Level to 1.6 it would not work until I set the workspace compiler compliance level to 1.6